# Explanation for Axiom of Choice and Choice Function

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory

Based on the definitions provided by Ciesielski,

> (Axiom of Choice) For every family $\mathcal{ F}$ of nonempty disjoint sets there exists a selector,that is, a set $S$ that intersects every $F\in \mathcal{F}$ in precisely one point.

I am trying to understand the following proof of

> If $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of nonempty sets then there is a function $f$ : $\mathcal{F}$ →  $\bigcup \mathcal{F}$ such that $f(X) ∈ X $ for every $X ∈ F$.

The following is the proof followed by my queries:

> Take a formula $\varphi (X, Y ) $ that can be abbreviated to $$ Y = \{X \} × X$$

(1) I am not clear here how or why $\varphi$ is formulated here. In particular I do not see the motivation for why the formula needs to be a Cartesian product of $X$ and a singleton set containing $X$. Would not just having $X$ or $X × X$ suffice? 
My guess is that is has something to do with an alternative formulation of how the axiom of choice is defined, that is,  
*For any indexed family $\{ A_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in J}$ of non empty sets, with $J \neq 0$ the Cartesian product is the set of all functions $$x : J \rightarrow  \prod_{\alpha \in J} A_\alpha$$ is non empty.* 
(2) But in either case I don’t see how the definitions provided by the book here and the ones italicised is equivalent.

> Notice that if $\varphi (X, Y ) $ and $\varphi (X, Y′ )$ hold then $Y = { X } × X = Y ′ $. In particular, $\varphi$ satisﬁes the assumptions of the replacement scheme axiom. So there exists a family $$ \mathcal{G} = \{Y : \exists X \in \mathcal{F}(\varphi(X,Y))\} = \{\{X\} × X: X\in \mathcal{F} \}.$$

(3) I think the above statement merely shows that I can construct some family of sets which has the specific property which I want from $\varphi$. Or is there more to it?

> Notive that the elements of $\mathcal{G}$ are non empty and that they are pairwise disjoint,since
> $$(\{X \} × X ) \cap ( \{X’\} × X’) = (\{X\} \cap\{X’\}) × (X \cap X’)$$
> Thus, by the axiom of choice, there is a selector $f$ for $\mathcal{G}$. Notice that $f$ is the desired function.

(4) Firstly, I do not see how the fact of being pairwise disjoint is really relevant here. I get that this is to align to Ciesielski‘s Axiom of Choice definition, but I think this query relates to a broader question of why being disjoint is a necessary condition.

My intuition is that it supports the single intersection definition, though maybe (by extension) I am really asking for the rationale for why he defines the Axiom of Choice this way.

(5) Lastly, I am not sure if this proof of the choice function really explains the difference between it and a *normal* function.

A *normal* function was defined earlier in the book to be  A relation $R \subset X * Y$ is called a function if
$$(\forall x,y_1,y_2)(xRy_1 \wedge xRy_2 \rightarrow y_1 = y_2)$$

Any form of clarifications would be welcomed. The proof is sourced from Set Theory for the Working Mathematician by Krzysztof Ciesielski.

Comment: The entire point of the $\{X\}\times X$ thing is that $\{\{X\}\times X: X\in \mathcal F\}$ is a family of *disjoint* sets (as stipulated in the first version of AC), whereas $\mathcal F$ is not, necessarily. (And that a choice from $\{X\}\times X$ is tantamount to a choice from $X,$ since it's just going to be $(X,x)$ for some $x\in X$.)

Comment: As to why we need the disjointness assumption, consider the family of nonempty sets $\{\{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{2\}\}.$ Can we find a selector that intersects each set in exactly one point? Also, just in general, this disjointness trick can be useful.... A lot of times form of the AC you're *proving* is the official one rather than the selector version. It can be a time saver to realize that it suffices to prove it for disjoint families.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I understand that if I were to take a selector to be $f : X \rightarrow X$ as defined for $X = \{1,2\} $then I cannot get a single intersection point. But it if that is true then would it not be possible to apply AoC for families of non disjoint sets?

Comment: Also could you elaborate on what the trick is specifically?

Comment: Pertaining to your first comment, does that mean that the *motive* for getting $\{ X\} \times X$ is arbitrary?

Comment: Sorry, that was probably confusing. I'm saying (and my example shows) that the disjointness assumption is necessary for what Ciesielski calls the Axiom of Choice (call it ACS - S for selector). It is *not* required (which is good cause it's not stated) for the version of AC that you are trying to prove (call it ACF - F for (choice) function). One way to think about proving the equivalence is to first prove the equivalence between ACS and ACFD, where "ACFD" is ACF, except we stipulate that $\mathcal F$ is pairwise disjoint. Then you can prove ACFD and ACF are equivalent using the 'trick'.

Comment: As for what the 'trick' is. It is that for any family $\mathcal F$ of nonempty sets, there is a corresponding pairwise disjoint family $F'=\{\{X\}\times X: X\in F\}$ and a choice function for $F'$ gives a choice function for $F$ by composing with $(X,x)\mapsto x.$ Not sure what you mean by the motive being "arbitrary"... the motive is that it makes the proof work.